# Updating PrimeFaces datatable inside nested controls?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

I'm pretty new to JSF and PrimeFaces. I am trying to update my datatable within a nested element. Everything I've tried to this point has either broken the page or been unsuccessful. Here is the markup:

```
 <h:form id="form2">
        <p:growl id="msgs" sticky="true" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"  />
        <ui:insert name="content">
                <ezcomp:header />
                <p:layout>
                    <p:layoutUnit position="west" >
                        <ezcomp:navigation />
                    </p:layoutUnit>
                    <p:layoutUnit position="center" >
                        <p:wizard widgetVar="wiz"> 
                            <p:tab id="flightInformation" title="General">
                                <p:panel header="Flight Information">
                                    <p:messages />
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">

                                        <p:outputLabel>Aircraft Name: </p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:inputText value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.aircraftName}" required="true" label="Aircraft Name"></p:inputText>
                                        <p:outputLabel>Airline Name: </p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:inputText value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.airlineName}" required="true" label="Airline Name"></p:inputText>
                                        <p:outputLabel>Flight Number: </p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:inputText value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.flightNumber}" required="true" label="Flight Number"></p:inputText>
                                        <p:outputLabel>Duration: </p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:inputMask value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.flightTime}" mask="99:99" placeholder="HH:MM" required="true" label="Flight Duration"></p:inputMask>
                                        <p:outputLabel>Base Price: </p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:inputText value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.basePrice}" required="true" label="Base Price"></p:inputText> 
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </p:panel>

                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab id="arrivalInfo" title="Departure And Arrival">
                                <p:panel header="Departure And Arrival Information">
                                    <p:messages />
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                                        <p:outputLabel>Departure Airport: </p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:inputText value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.departureAirport}" required="true" label="Departure Airport"></p:inputText>
                                        <p:outputLabel>Departure Airport Code: </p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:inputText value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.departureAirportCode}" required="true" maxlength="3" label="Departure Airport Code"></p:inputText>
                                        <p:outputLabel>Departure Date and Time: </p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:calendar value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.departure}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" required="true" label="Departure Date and Time" />
                                        <p:outputLabel>Arrival Airport: </p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:inputText value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.arrivalAirport}" required="true" label="Arrival Airport"></p:inputText>
                                        <p:outputLabel>Arrival Airport Code: </p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:inputText value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.arrivalAirportCode}" required="true" maxlength="3" label="Arrival Airport Code"></p:inputText>
                                        <p:outputLabel>Arrival Date and Time: </p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:calendar value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.arrival}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" required="true" label="Arrival Date and Time"/>


                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </p:panel>
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab id="seatingInfo" title="Seating">
                                <p:panel header="Seating Information">
                                    <p:messages />
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                                        <p:outputLabel>Economy</p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:spinner value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.economyClassSeats}" required="true" label="Total Economy Seats" />
                                        <p:outputLabel>Business</p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:spinner value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.businessClassSeats}" required="true" label="Total Business Seats" />
                                        <p:outputLabel>First Class</p:outputLabel>
                                        <p:spinner value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight.firstClassSeats}" required="true" label="Total First Class Seats" />
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </p:panel>                   
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab id="confirmation" title="Confirmation">
                                <p:panel header="Confirm Flight">
                                    <p:messages />

                                    <p:dataGrid value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flight}" var="f" columns="2">
                                        <div style="width:50%;">
                                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" >
                                                <p:outputLabel>Aircraft Name: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.aircraftName}"></h:outputText>
                                                <p:outputLabel>Airline Name: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.airlineName}" ></h:outputText>
                                                <p:outputLabel>Flight Number: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.flightNumber}" ></h:outputText>
                                                <p:outputLabel>Duration: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.flightTime}"></h:outputText>
                                                <p:outputLabel>Base Price: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.basePrice}"></h:outputText>

                                                <p:outputLabel>Arrival Airport: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.arrivalAirport}" ></h:outputText>
                                                <p:outputLabel>Arrival Airport Code: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.arrivalAirportCode}" ></h:outputText>
                                                <p:outputLabel>Arrival Date and Time: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.arrival}" />

                                                <p:outputLabel>Departure Airport: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.departureAirport}" ></h:outputText>
                                                <p:outputLabel>Departure Airport Code: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.departureAirportCode}" ></h:outputText>
                                                <p:outputLabel>Departure Date and Time: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.departure}" />

                                                <p:outputLabel>Economy: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.economyClassSeats}" ></h:outputText>
                                                <p:outputLabel>Business: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.businessClassSeats}" ></h:outputText>
                                                <p:outputLabel>First Class: </p:outputLabel>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{f.firstClassSeats}" ></h:outputText>
                                            </h:panelGrid>
                                        </div>

                                        <p:commandButton value="Add To Submission" ajax="true" action="#{flightWizard.addAnother(f)}" oncomplete="PF('wiz').loadStep('flightInformation',false)" />
                                    </p:dataGrid>
                                </p:panel>          

                            </p:tab>
                        </p:wizard>
                    </p:layoutUnit>
                    <p:layoutUnit id='submissionUnit' position="east" size='40%' >
                        <p:dataTable id='submissionTable' var="x" value="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flights}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
                            <p:column style="font-size:0.8em;" headerText="Flight Number">
                                <h:outputText value="#{x.flightNumber}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column style="font-size:0.8em;" headerText="Arrival Code">
                                <h:outputText value="#{x.arrivalAirportCode}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column style="font-size:0.8em;" headerText="Arrival">
                                <h:outputText value="#{x.arrival}" />
                            </p:column>                                    
                            <p:column style="font-size:0.8em;" headerText="Departure Code">
                                <h:outputText value="#{x.departureAirportCode}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column style="font-size:0.8em;" headerText="Departure">
                                <h:outputText value="#{x.departure}" />
                            </p:column>                                    
                            <p:column style="font-size:0.8em;" headerText="Edit">
                                <p:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{flightWizard.flightMB.changeFlightByIndex(rowIndex)}" oncomplete="PF('wiz').loadStep('flightInformation',false)"/>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>    
                        <br/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Submit" immediate="true" disabled="#{flightWizard.flightMB.flights.size()==0?true:false}" action="#{flightBean.insertFlight(flightWizard.flightMB.flights)}"/>
                    </p:layoutUnit>
                </p:layout>                
        </ui:insert>
```

I am trying to update the datatable in the third layout unit from the second layout unit via the command button.

I've tried using the update property of the command button, but all it seems to do is break the wizard and doesn't allow me to enter the tab it is on.

I've also tried updating it from the bean like so:

```
public void addAnother(Flight f){
    flightMB.addFlightToCreate(f);
    flightMB.setFlight(new Flight());
    RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    // reqCtx.update("form2:submissionUnit");
    reqCtx.update("form2:layoutUnit");

}
```

Any help at this point would be appreciated.

Comment: don't try to update the layout use an update `:form2:submissionTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating the entire `p:layoutUnit`. You can update the Datatable or you can put a `h:panelGroup` around it and update that.

@XHTML:

```
<h:form id="form1">
<p:layoutUnit id='submissionUnit'>
<h:panelGroup id="tablePG">
<p:dataTable id='submissionTable'>
...
</p:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
</p:layoutUnit>
</h:form>
```

@ManagedBean:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form1:tablePG");
```

And please note that while updating component from `ManagedBean` using `RequestContext` then you don't need to provide `:` at beginning of your component Id.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just what I was looking for.